# Dockerfile - get contents of the root directory

Tags: java, docker, maven, docker-compose, monorepo

I'm building images of multiple services from `docker-compose.yml`. For eg if there are 3 services a,b & c and there are changes in `service a` folder, the image would be built using the command `docker-compose a-service`. however the service in the `docker-compose.yml` file has been written in a way where it is given a build context. for e.g

```
services:
   a-service:
       container-name: a-service
       build:
          context: ./services/a
```

and this is the project file structure

```
java-project/
├─ docker-compose.yml
├─ services/
│  ├─ a/
│  │  ├─ Dockerfile
│  │  ├─ pom.xml
│  ├─ b/
│  │  ├─ pom.xml
│  │  ├─ Dockerfile
├─ pom.xml
```

Dockerfile

```
#
# Build stage
#
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11 as build
***fails at this steps****
RUN mvn clean install -DskipTests

#
# Package stage
#
FROM amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
COPY src/main/resources/META-INF/xxx xxxx
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Now when the service a is built, the `Dockerfile` present in `service a` folder is referenced and also the `pom.xml` present in the `service a` folder is referenced. However, I want the `pom.xml` present in the root directory of the project to be referenced for the maven build as part of the image creation process (maven build requires the pom.xml to create jar files. These jar files would be copied to the image). I tried the following in the `service a` `Dockerfile` but still no luck. Any idea how I can achieve this?
`RUN cd ../../pom.xml`
or

```
RUN mkdir tmp-context
RUN cp -R ../../pom.xml tmp-context
```

or
`COPY ../../pom.xml .`
tldr - How do i get the contents of the project in the root directory from a sub directory in a `Dockerfile`

Comment: You are aware that the context is a _copy_ of the directory given?  Files outside of that are simply not included in the copy, and therefore not available to Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `context` and add the location of your `dockerfile` like so:

```yaml
services:
  a-service:
    container-name: a-service
      build:
        context: ./
        dockerfile: ./services/a/Dockerfile
```

Comment: the build starts with `Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.01GB` and errors at the step where mvn is used `mvn clean install -DskipTests`. `The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/)`

Comment: Did you check to ensure that your files are being copied to the correct locations in the Docker container?

Comment: i have updated the question with the contents of the Dockerfile

Comment: The error states `The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/)` which makes sense, because you still need to `COPY` your POM file in the Dockerfile so that it can be found when building the image. For example, `COPY pom.xml .`

Comment: this is sending almost 4gb to docker daemon compared to 200mb earlier. weird since I'm not even copying the entire contents of the project and just the `pom.xml`

Comment: It would be good to ask the reason for that in a separate question. If you found this answer helpful, please accept it for future searchers

Comment: `.dockerignore` is useful for pruning what is included in the context sent.  You rarely want `.git` for instance.